# mitmproxy as a chain proxy, without SSL decryption

Tags: ssl, proxy, mitmproxy

I want to use mitmproxy, as a chain proxy, meaning, I want all my services to connect to mitmproxy which in turn is configured to connect to an external proxy, I did that just fine, using the upstream mode but I could not find anything in the documents to disable SSL decryption, so unless I trust the certificate on all clients, I cannot use this setup.

Is there such an option, and if not, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, you can append `--allow-hosts 127\.0\.0\.1:443` for example, which will instruct mitm to only decrypt traffic to the specified addressed, thus ignoring decryption for other hosts